# Codeigniter not working with Verots class.upload

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, upload, image-manipulation

I have encountered a problem I can't really figure out - I can't get the class.upload to work properly with CodeIgniter framework.

To implement it I tried the code snippet supplied [here](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewreply/845667/) but it is still not working. I've turned logging on and all I get is

> ERROR - 2012-05-06 17:51:24 --> Severity: Warning  -->
>   include_once(application/core/MY_Imaging.php) [function.include-once]: failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory
>   /var/www/mypage/application/config/config.php 376 
>   ERROR - 2012-05-06
>   17:51:24 --> Severity: Warning  --> include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening
>   'application/core/MY_Imaging.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')
>   /var/www/mypage/application/config/config.php 376

It tries to include `MY_Imaging.php` for reasons unknown to me. I haven't made any libraries for codeigniter, but I know that by using `$this->load->library("imaging");` it should load library Imaging which it is not doing.

I'm currently out of ideas on how to solve this.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you provided clearly says

```
1. Copy the folder class.upload to libraries directory;

2. Create a new library with this code:
```

Looking at your error.. You haven't created the library `MY_Imaging` in `application/library`

Comment: Well, that's the problem. The code clearly tells you to create a file called `Imaging.php` in the `libraries` folder (By looking at the file location in the comment on the footer) which I have done, I have also called the library properly afaik. If I have to make an `MY_Imaging` class I've got no idea what class it should extend as the `Imaging` class in libraries folder already extends class.upload

Comment: The error says it could not load the file. and the include statement is in config.php.. can you post what you have in config.php in line 376

Comment: I feel ashamed and relieved at the same time. I guess I just somehow skipped the config.php part of the error message - I had native php autoloading created there for no reason. Thank you for pointing it out and sorry for taking the time.